# How does the variable assignment "x, = 1,2" work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, variable-assignment

the value of the variable a and b after the execution of the following code :

```
a = 1, 2, 3 
b, = 1, 2, 3
```

the result is

```
 a =  [1, 2, 3]
 b =  1
```

why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comma makes ruby think you're going to do a parallel assignment, where b and another variable will be assigned through the same expression like so:

```
b, c = 1, 2
```

results in b == 1 and c == 2.

So here ruby assigns the first value on the right side to b, and expects to assign the next value on the right to another variable, but finds none, so it discards the remaining values.

Answer (score 2):

It's ruby's Parallel Assignment.
`a = 1, 2, 3` means put array `[1, 2, 3]` to `a`.
`b, = 1, 2, 3` means put 1 to `b`, and 2 to ? and 3 to ?. If you try

```
b,c,d = 1,2,3
```

you see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby you can do parallel assignment. So for example: a, b = 1, 2 means a == 1 and b == 2
In this example: a, b, = 1, 2, 3. a == 1 and b == 2 and there is no variable to assign the value 3.
In this example: a, b = 1. a == 1 and b is nil